# Best format for importing to excel

Tags: c#, excel, file, file-format

I need to output table data from my c# Application that will be imported to Excel. The data contains date/time that needs to be correctly imported to Excel (as dates). I need a file format that is supported by the .net framework on one hand and on the other is easily imported to Excel.

Anyone?

/jorx

Answer (score 1):

Try a straight text file in ***.csv*** format.  For example:

[image]

will open in Excel like:

[image]

You can later modify the format to suite your needs.

**EDIT#1:**

Here is a better example:

[image]

Comment: This in a nutshell. Heck, in my office, every time someone asks for an Excel file output, this is what I give them.

Comment: @Gary.Taylor717  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Wow, didn't even know that's how Excel used formatting on CSVs. Thank you sir!